# Azure Iot Logic Component

Tags: c#, .net, azure, iot

I have a sensor that collects temperature data and sends it to my Iot Hub. This data must be evaluated. In some cases, the data must be sent to another device. Currently, I have a C# console application that does the job. It subscribes to my Iot Hub and reads the data from my partitions. As far as I understood, there must be an Azure component that should be used instead of a console application. My question is, what component can be used in order to receive data from an IoT device in order to process the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Azure Functions seems like a good fit. Here are [some](https://medium.com/medialesson/iothubtrigger-azure-function-and-azure-iot-hub-e45ea819e6b5) [resources](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/how-to-use-azure-functions-with-iot-hub-message-routing/)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions is a serverless compute service that enables you to run code on-demand without having to explicitly provision or manage infrastructure. Use Azure Functions to run a script or piece of code in response to a variety of events.

you can utilize it instead of writing in a console app and scheduling it .